# Как сделать отправление формы без перезагрузки с помощью Django и Ajax

Tags: ajax, django

Я google'лил этот вопрос , но на сайтах показано только с помощью php и ajax.

Comment: Реализация `AJAX`-запроса со стороны клиента будет одинаковой и для `PHP`, и для `Django`.